# matlab equivalent of dot star in python

Tags: python, matlab

I am working on a matlab conversion code.
what is equivalent of .* in matlab with python?

```
len = sum(sqrt(sum(v.*v)))/N;
```

where v is numpy array :

```
v =  [array([-35289.38919481, -30575.56015338, -21456.41798462, ...,
    19796.17331542,  11216.34277023,   6977.87432284])]
N = 18225
```

In such cases, how will I convert code to python?

Comment: What is the expected result of this on Matlab? `sum(...)` should return a number, so why do you also have an outer `sum` around the `sqrt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For numpy arrays, just using * will do the element-wise multiplication as in Matlab's `.*`
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

you can use,

```
len = numpy.sum(numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum(v[0] * v[0], axis=0))) / N
```

Note: If you want to use matrices instead of arrays in numpy, you have to use the `multiply` method.

Comment: but v is in array so we should use v[0]?

Answer (score 1):

```
v_squared_sum = v.dot(v.transpose()) 
len_ = np.sum(np.sqrt(v_squared_sum)) / N
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([1,2,3])
N = 3
len_ = np.sqrt(np.dot(v, v)) / N
print(len_)
```

Result:

```
1.24721912892
```

Do not use `len` as a variable name, because this shadows the built-in length function [`len()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).